# I need to sent the body in form of Form data

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, developer-console

I am posting the data to endpoint url through http callouts from developer console and getting response "200 ok" and in body of response i am getting an error message of

> "{"IsSuccess":false,"Message":"10 digit card number cannot be empty"}"

even though i have inserted 10 digit card number but when i am trying to insert the same data using POSTMAN then data is posted and also getting created in the database but when i am posting through APEX then it is not getting inserted bcoz of the above error.

Also i am attaching the screenshot of POSTMAN from where i am inserting the data in form data format.
Can anyone please help me on my query.
[image: POSTMAN Screen shot successfull]

```
Http p=New Http();    
Httprequest req=new Httprequest();
    Info_Saloon__c MyToken = Info_Saloon__c.getInstance('IFS Links');
    req.setendpoint(MyToken.Info_Saloon_Token__c);
    req.setmethod('POST');

    string Body=MyToken.Token_Body__c;  
    req.setbody(body);
    req.setheader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    System.HttpResponse response1 = new System.Http().send(req);
    system.debug(''+response1.getBody());
    string AuthorizationToken;
    System.JSONParser jp=JSON.createParser(response1.getBody());
    while(jp.nextToken()!=null){
        if(jp.getText()=='access_token'){
            jp.nextToken();
            AuthorizationToken=jp.getText();
        }
    }
    Http http = new Http();

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(MyToken.Insert_Data__c);
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW');


    request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+AuthorizationToken);


    request.setBody('[{"Full_Card_Number__c" :"1234567895","First_Name__c" :"Avesh","Last_Name__c :"Test","Contact_Email__c" :"test@test.com","Category__c" :"DEL","Conference_Type__c" :"STRAT","Conference_Selection__c" :"ST4A","Payment_Status_Interface__c" :"NPAID"}]');

    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    // Parse the JSON response
    if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                     response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        System.debug(response.getBody());
    } else {
        System.debug(response.getBody());
    }
```

Comment: Well, is the remote service expecting `multipart/form-data`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, or JSON payload? You're sending JSON with the wrong Content-Type right now.

Comment: @DavidReed The remote string is expecting the body in form data so i think it is Multipart/form-data correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I can't correct you because I don't know the requirements of the service you're calling (or even what it is). Your screenshot looks like you are sending `form-data` encoding from Postman. If that's indeed what the service requires, your Apex should do the same, rather than sending JSON with the incorrect `Content-Type` `multipart/form-data` header.

Comment: @DavidReed I have removed this header but still getting the same issue. request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Comment: and my service want the data in form data format only which i have posted in the screenshot

Comment: Then you need to send it in that format. Changing the content type header doesn't convert the JSON data you're setting in the body.

Comment: Can you please help me what change i need to do in my code :)

Comment: I can't write your code for you. (That's also not what we do at Stack Exchange). Please see [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better sense of what SFSE needs from you and can provide.

Comment: I have already written the code and just need the help to debug anyways thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code

```
Http p=New Http();    
    Httprequest req=new Httprequest();
        Info_Saloon__c MyToken = Info_Saloon__c.getInstance('IFS Links');
        req.setendpoint(MyToken.Info_Saloon_Token__c);
        req.setmethod('POST');

        string Body=MyToken.Token_Body__c;  
        req.setbody(body);
        req.setheader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        System.HttpResponse response1 = new System.Http().send(req);
        system.debug(''+response1.getBody());
        string AuthorizationToken;
        System.JSONParser jp=JSON.createParser(response1.getBody());
        while(jp.nextToken()!=null){
            if(jp.getText()=='access_token'){
                jp.nextToken();
                AuthorizationToken=jp.getText();
            }
        }
    Http http = new Http();

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(MyToken.Insert_Data__C);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW');
        request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ AuthorizationToken);


    List<registration__C> Reg=[SELECT Salutation__c, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c ,Account_Name__c, Contact_Email__c, Category__c, Conference_Type__c, Conference_Selection__c, Payment_Status_Interface__c,  Full_Card_Number__c
    FROM Registration__C limit 2];
    for(integer i=0;i<Reg.size();i++)
    {
        //request.setbody(body);
    request.setbody('------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Full_Card_Number__c\"\r\n\r\n'+Reg[i].Full_Card_Number__c+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Salutation__c\"\r\n\r\n'+Reg[i].Salutation__c+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"First_Name__c\"\r\n\r\n'+Reg[i].First_Name__C+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Last_Name__c\"\r\n\r\n'+Reg[i].Last_Name__C+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Account_Name__c\"\r\n\r\n'+ Reg[i].Account_Name__C+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Contact_Email__c\"\r\n\r\n'+Reg[i].Contact_Email__C+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Category__c\"\r\n\r\n'+Reg[i].Category__C+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Conference_Type__c\"\r\n\r\n'+Reg[i].Conference_Type__C+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Conference_Selection__c\"\r\n\r\n'+Reg[i].Conference_Selection__C+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Payment_Status_Interface__c\"\r\n\r\n'+Reg[i].Payment_Status_Interface__C+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                         response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
    }
```